# Showing that two spaces are isomorphic

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by: for all x,y in $\mathbb{R}$:

$ x\sim y$ iff $x - y \in \mathbb{Q}$

I also have an equivalence relation at $\mathbb{R^2}$ defined by: ($x_0$, $x_1$) $\sim_2$ ($y_0$, $y_1$) if and only if $x_0 - y_0 \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x_1 - y_1 \in \mathbb{Q}$

Proof that the structure ($\mathbb{R}$,$\sim$) is isomorphic with ($\mathbb{R^2}$,$\sim_2$)

I already know in both structures I have countable many elements per equivalence class, and there are uncountably many, the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, of that classes. So I wanted to make such an isomorphism that sends classes to other classes, but I don't know how to do it.

Is it sufficient to use the axiom of choice uncountable many times to choose a new class every time?

Answer (score 1):

Constructing an explicit bijection is going to be hard and not particularly enlightening. The intended solution is most probably more abstract than that.

Do you already know that $|A\times B|=\max(|A|,|B|)$ when at least one of $A$ and $B$ is infinite?

Can you prove that each equivalence class (in both structures) is countably infinite?

Since $|\mathbb R|=|\mathbb R^2|$, what does this say about the *number of equivalence classes* in each structure? (Hint: not merely that there are "uncountably many").

If you can show that there are equally many equivalence classes, what you have proved is *exactly* that there is *some* bijection between one set of equivalence classes and the other, no matter that you may not have a nice way to *define* that bijection.

Comment: Thanks! I see now I was not quite specific about the number of equivalence classes but I already knew that they are as many as $\mathbb{R}$. 

What's hard for me to get is the last part. Is it right that I need the axiom of choice to conclude I can make a bijection, out of the fact that I have equally many equivalence classes on both sides?

Comment: @Loes: Once you know there are equally many equivalence classes, you don't need Choice to conclude that there is a bijection _that takes equivalence classes to equivalence classes_. (This is exactly what "equally many" _means_). But you do need Choice in order to extend this bijection to a bijection that works on individual elements and goes directly $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$. Specifically, you need to choose a bijection between each equivalence class and $\mathbb N$ for all equivalence classes simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to start with a bijection $\varphi:\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Q^2$. $\Bbb Q$ is one of the $\sim_1$-equivalence classes, and $\Bbb Q^2$ is one of the $\sim_2$-equivalence classes, so this is at least a start. Now we want to extend $\varphi$ to a bijection $\widehat\varphi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$ in such a way that for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$, $x\sim_1 y$ iff $\widehat\varphi(x)\sim_2\widehat\varphi(y)$.

One nice way is to appeal to the axiom of choice twice to get a set $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ that contains exactly one member of each $\sim_1$-class except the class $\Bbb Q$ and a set $B\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ that contains exactly one member of each $\sim_2$-class except the class $\Bbb Q^2$. $|A|=|B|=|\Bbb R|$ (why?), so there is a bijection $\psi:A\to B$. Now let

$$\widehat\varphi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
\varphi(x),&\text{if }x\in\Bbb Q\\
\psi(a)+\varphi(x-a),&\text{if }x\sim_1 a\in A\;,
\end{cases}$$

and prove that $\widehat\varphi$ has the desired properties. (Addition in $\Bbb R^2$ is, as usual, component-wise.)